# Is $\phi$ convex if it is continuous and $\phi \Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\le \frac{1}{2}\phi (x) +\frac{1}{2} \phi (y)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Assume that $\phi$ is continuous real function on $(a,b)$ such that $$\phi\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\le \frac{1}{2}\phi (x) +\frac{1}{2} \phi (y)$$ for all $x,y \in (a,b)$. Prove that $\phi$ is convex.

We need to show that for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have $\phi(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda \cdot\phi(x)+(1-\lambda)\cdot \phi (y) \quad\forall x,y \in (a,b)$. I had drawn some figures and it was coming out to be convex, for rigorous proof I was thinking of proving this for rationals $x,y$ then using continuity argument we can prove it for all $x,y$ but I'm not able to do so.

Comment: This looks like a good candidate for the contrapositive: Assume $\phi$ is continuous and _not_ convex (i.e., the graph lies strictly above the secant line over some closed, bounded interval) and find $x$ and $y$ violating the inequality in the hypothesis.

Comment: yes that will be a good geometrical argument but I'm looking for some rigorous proof.

Comment: Jensen's inequality?

Comment: But this is the definition of convex function. Unless you are using other definition.

Comment: @Tolaso I'm using the definition I mentioned in my sketch of proof

Comment: Then replace $\lambda$ with $1/2$ and you are done. You've proved it. Actually this is known as Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @Tolaso, I think you're not getting my point , I've to show that $\phi(\lambda x+ (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda \cdot\phi(x)+(1-\lambda)\cdot \phi (y) \quad\forall x,y \in (a,b)$ given that $\phi\Big(\frac{x+y}{2}\Big)\le \frac{1}{2}\phi (x) +\frac{1}{2} \phi (y)$

Comment: @Neeraj: At this stage my comment is moot (since the question is a duplicate), but it's a perfectly rigorous analytic suggestion. :) (Naturally, you have to translate the statement about secant lines into inequalities: "There exist $x < y$ such that $\phi(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) > \lambda \phi(x) + (1 - \lambda) \phi(y)$ for $0 < \lambda < 1$" and establish the truth of this assertion.)

Comment: You can prove that $\phi(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \le \lambda \phi(x) + (1-\lambda)\phi(y)$ whenever $\lambda = p/2^n$ and $p$ is odd and $0 < p < 2^n$, by induction on $n$.  (For $n=1$, this is exactly your assumption.)  Consider the cases $p < 2^{n-1}$ and $p>2^{n-1}$ separately.  Then use continuity to prove the result for all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.